# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar varias filas en una sola consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Una analogía es como el insert en una sola consulta

```
INSERT INTO table1 (First, Last) 
VALUES 
    ('Fred', 'Smith'), 
    ('John', 'Smith'), 
    ('Michael', 'Smith'), 
    ('Robert', 'Smith');
```

Pero lo que deseo es un update en una sola consulta en mysql

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Un `UPDATE` no es lo mismo que un `INSERT`, pues actúa sobre valores que se supone que ya existen. ¿Qué es lo que quieres, actualizar varias filas que ya existen con los mismos datos? En ese caso puedes usar un `WHERE` para indicar un criterio que haga la actualización sobre esa filas. En cualquier caso, conviene que pongas en la pregunta lo que has intentado.

Comment: la sentencia `UPDATE` sin un `WHERE` actualiza el 100% de los registros, si lo que deseas es actualizar un determinado número de registros, usas entonces por ejemplo un `WHERE` y colocas bajo que parámetros lo haga

Comment: Me parece que no tenés esa opción para UPDATE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Si lo que quieres es actualizar varios registros según un criterio común usa where como te apuntan. Si lo que quieres es seleccionar registros arbitrarios y actualizar cada uno con un valor distinto, en función de clave, haciéndolo en una sola sentencia para ahorrar código, aunque es factible no te lo recomiendo porque será demasiado complicado de mantener. Por favor reformula la pregunta para explicar tu objetivo. ¿Es ahorrar código? ¿Control transaccional? ¿Mejorar el rendimiento al actualizar muchos registros? así podrás recibir una respuesta más adecuada a tu interés.

Comment: Necesitas hacer u update. La clave es el Set, donde decides que es lo que cambias y Where que es donde decides a quien cambias

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer varias consultas a la vez es hacer varias variables del mismo nombre y ejecutarlas como una, con la función `multi_query()`.

```
<?php
   $conexion = new mysqli("servidor","usuario","contrasena","DB"); //conecta a la base de datos
   if(!$conexion){ //si da un error la conexión lo siguiente no se ejecutará y se imprimirá cuyo error
      die("Error en la conexion de DB: ".$conexion->connect_error)
   }
   $valor1_table1 = "string";
   $valor2_table1 = "string";
   $valor1_table2 = "string";
   $valor2_table2 = "string";
   //Si quieres capturar el valor de un input se hace con $_POST['nombre_atributo_tipo_name'];
   $sql = "UPDATE table1 SET columna1='".$valor1_table1."', columna2='".$valor2_table1."'";
   $sql = "UPDATE table2 SET columna1='".$valor1_table2."', columna2='".$valor2_table2."'";
   if($conexion->multi_query($sql) === TRUE){
         echo "registros actualizados";
   }else{
         echo "hubo un error.";
   }
   $conexion->close();
?>
```

Para más información visita: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

PD:

Para actualizar datos en la DB es `UPDATE`. No `INSERT`, ya que con `INSERT` insertas nuevos registros.

**INSERT**

> INSERT INTO table (columna1,columna2...) VALUES ('valor1','valor2'...)

**UPDATE**

> UPDATE table SET columna1='valor1', columna2='valor2',... WHERE columna3='valor3'

**DELETE**

> DELETE FROM table WHERE columna1='valor1',...

**SELECT**

> SELECT columna1,columna2... FROM table1  //(*) para seleccionar todas las columnas

**TRUNCATE**

> TRUNCATE TABLE table1  //Vacia completamente una tabla

Answer (score 0):

MySQL te permite una forma más legible de combinar múltiples actualizaciones en una sola consulta. Esto parece ajustarse mejor al escenario que describes, es mucho más fácil de leer y evita esas múltiples condiciones difíciles de desenredar.

INSERT INTO table (id, row2, row_3, row_4)
VALUES
('622057', '12082014', 'student', '17389551'),
('2913659', '12082014', 'assistant','17389551'),
('6160230', '12082014', 'admin', '17389551')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id=VALUES(id), row_2=VALUES(row_2)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. sin embargo, la pregunta es como hacer esomismo con update... aca, respondiste lo mismo que dice la pregunta... por favor mira [answer] y de paso hace el [tour] asi sabes como funciona el sitio!